# Is it possible that isIdleTimerDisabled is ignored in some occasions?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible that even when `isIdleTimerDisabled` is set to true, it could still be ignored under certain circumstances? For instance, if the device is in **Low Power Mode** (e.g., when `ProcessInfo.processInfo.isLowPowerModeEnabled` returns `true`), could the screen still turn off despite setting `isIdleTimerDisabled` to true in the AppDelegate?

I have received feedback from some users that the app screen shuts down after some time (there was no incoming phone calls during that time). However, it is difficult for me to reproduce the issue. So my question is, could the screen turn off if `isIdleTimerDisabled` is set to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Turning on Low Power Mode forces autolock after 30 sec. I have tested this on my phone with an example app. The observed behaviour is:

When `isIdleTimerDisabled` set to true and low battery is on

1. iPhone is connected to charger -> screen will not turn of after 30 sec
2. iPhone is on battery -> screen will turn off after 30 sec

Comment: Its strange, cause for me when I set idle timer to false, it works even on Low Battery mode without the charger. Is this documented somewhere?